# Can some one explain why program doesn't end?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

> Hi, I'm new to the java thread.I'm trying to figure out what is the
>   wait() and notify() methods.So I wrote simple programme but I can't
>   find the reason for infinity execution.Please, can someone help me to solve this?

```
public class StairCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lst = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        Test1 t1 = new Test1(lst);
        t1.setName("Test 1 ");
        Test2 t2 = new Test2(lst);
        t2.setName("Test 2 ");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Test1 extends Thread {
    int[] line ;
    public Test1(int[] lst) {
        this.line = lst;
    }
    public void run(){
        synchronized(line) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try{
                    if(i == 2) line.wait();
               } catch (Exception e) {

               }
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + line[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Test2 extends Thread {
    int[] line ;
    public Test2(int[] lst) {
        this.line = lst;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(line) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + line[i]);
            }
        }
        try {
            line.notify();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try system.exit(0) after your task is done?

Comment: You're code is getting a java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException in line 45.

Comment: Yes . I think the problem is in threads.But I can't figure it out.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) {  }` is an excellent way to thoroughly confuse yourself when trying to debug your program.  When exceptions happen, they silently disappear down a deep dark hole and you're left clueless.  Never, never, never, NEVER under any circumstances do yourself that cruel disservice.  At least put `ex.printStackTrace();` in there .

Comment: The javadoc for o.wait() and o.notify() don't explain how they were meant to be used. See the tutorial instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StairCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lst = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        Test1 t1 = new Test1(lst);
        t1.setName("Test 1 ");
        Test2 t2 = new Test2(lst);
        t2.setName("Test 2 ");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Test1 extends Thread {
    private final int[] line ;
    Test1(int[] lst) {
        this.line = lst;
    }
    public void run(){
        synchronized(line) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try{
                    if(i == 2) line.wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + line[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Test2 extends Thread {
    private final int[] line ;
    Test2(int[] lst) {
        this.line = lst;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(line) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + line[i]);
            }
        }
        try {
            synchronized (line) {
                line.notify();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

try this code is this the result you expected? if not let me know what is the expect result.

I have added e.printStackTrace(); to the catch blocks and checked weather if there was an Exception, and there was an exception, the exception was at line 45 in notify() so I have surrounded the notify with synchronized statement.

```
        synchronized (line) {
            line.notify();
        }
```

Comment: Explain your code and how it anwers the OP's question. A big code drop without explanation is not useful.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Most of it is the OP's code, but I will make an edit and tell what I have changed.

Comment: First I want print 1 and 2 in t1 thread and wait the t1.Next print 1 to 5 in t2 thread and notify to the t1 thread.Then print 3 to 5.

Comment: yep, the code I have provided does that. you just needed to synchronized it, happy coding :)